# Bobcat for leveling swimming pool ot tiller?

Tags: pool, leveling

I have a 24ft by 52 inch pool. Need to level ground and remove 10 to 12 inches on high side. After about 5 inches it's all compacted clay. Can i use a tiller to keep breaking up soil and shoveling out, or should I just get the bobcat and do it. I ask because I need a tiller anyway for the yard, so figured to save the extra  $250 on the bobcat rental maybe I could try a tiller... but I don't want to waste my time if it wont budge the compacted clay.  This is a year old new construction home. Thanks.

Comment: A bobcat will cut clay if you don't dig two deep and take smaller bites. Most folks that haven't used equipment tend to take two much off without realising it so make sure to check your depth or you will be backfilling.

Comment: What may be helpful for other's to consider for forming an answer is to disclose where in the world your pool resides.

Comment: In the midwest just outside Chicago.